# Может ли ASP.NET сайт получить доступ к файловой системе юзера?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, веб-программирование

Например, юзер заходит на сайт, указывает директорию на своем компе, сайт получает дерево каталогов и что-то делает на своей стороне.

Comment: Почти все тэги мимо, начните с клиентской части https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Answer (score 1):

Нет, так как сервер выполняет операции на стороне сервера (не клиента!).

Чтобы Вам сделать что-то с компьютером пользователя, Вам необходимо поставить какой-нибудь клиент на его компьютер и сообщать серверу нужную информацию, например, посредством REST-запросов, или WCF, или SignalR. И далее в зависимости от ответов сервера выполнять манипуляции на стороне пользователя через Ваше клиентское приложение.

Comment: Даже никакими скриптами нельзя это сделать?

Comment: Для доступа к большинству каталогов в современных ОС нужны права администратора. Теоретически, клиент может отправлять доступные пользователю каталоги (его домашнюю папку), но это нужно писать специального клиента. То есть, это уже не ASP.NET

Comment: А как же html5 со своим File API?

Comment: @eastwing, я же это и написал: "поставить какой-нибудь клиент". Наверное, надо уточнить, что это самописный, то есть приложение которое мы пишим:)

Comment: @PrimusSingularis, html5 выполняется на стороне пользователя, по сути это тоже можно назвать "клиентским приложением", но код который отрабатывает на стороне сервера сам никак не может влиять на изменение каталогов пользователя.

Comment: @iluxa1810, вы можете, например, через HTML File API, о котором уже сказали, получить список каталогов и отдать их на сервер, но что-то сделать с файловой системой пользователя напрямую с сервера Вы не можете.

Comment: @Umed, _через HTML File API, о котором уже сказали, получить список каталогов и отдать их на сервер_ - что, правда? звучит так, будто сейчас любой сайт может просканить мои диски и отсылать на сервер что ему вздумается, что, само собой, не так

Comment: @Umed Я, собственно, Илюхе отвечал, ник не проставил :)

Comment: @Qutrix, я понятия не имею как работает HTML File API, другой человек привёл его в пример, я предположил что через эту штуку можно как-то узнать какую-то структуру каталогов на диске, но в своём ответе, под которым ведём обсуждение, я говорил о клиентском приложении.

Comment: @Umed, _через эту штуку можно как-то узнать какую-то структуру каталогов на диске_ - нет